# How do i avoid duplicate record inserting in target table when source table not having foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

We can usually avoid duplicate insertion to target table by using merge query/ join query by mapping and checking conditions. But how can we handle without foreign key constraint to avoid duplicate insertion.

TableA - target table

```
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|  Id    | RecNo  |   Name    |   Salary  |  Date      |
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|anyGuid |Guid1   | Name1     |  10000    | 19-07-2015 |
|anyGuid |Guid2   | Name2     |  20000    | 20-07-2015 |
|anyGuid |Guid3   | Name3     |  30000    | 19-07-2015 |
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

TableB - source temp table

```
+--------+--------+-----------+------------+
| RecNo  | Name   | Salary    | Date       |
+--------+--------+-----------+------------+
|Guid3   |Name3   | 30000     | 19-07-2015 |
|Guid4   |Name4   | 40000     | 20-07-2015 |
|Guid5   |Name5   | 40000     | 21-07-2105 |
+--------+--------+-----------+------------+
```

Now, I need to insert all rows from `TableB` into `TableA` target table, but it should not insert rows that already exist in `TableA`.

Example: should not insert 1st record of source TableB into TableA.

**Note:** There is no foreign key between TableA and TableB.

How can we handle this case smartly? Suggestions please.

Comment: Why not add the foreign key? It sounds like you want to enforce it anyway so why not add it to your system? That is why they exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TableA (ID, RecNo, Salary, [Date])
SELECT  RecNo, Name, Salary, [Date]
FROM TableB B 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM TableA 
                  WHERE B.Name = RecNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TableA (RecNo, Name, Salary, Date)
SELECT b.RecNo, b.Name, b.Salary, d.Date
FROM TableB b
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA a ON a.RecNo = b.RecNo
WHERE a.RecNo IS NULL
```

This assumes RecNo provides uniqueness.  The left outer join will match on records with the same RecNo between the two tables, and the where condition (a.RecNo IS NULL) will find the records in TableB that don't exist in TableA.